# Having problems parsing string to datetime

Tags: r, datetime

I'm having some problems parsing a string to datetime.

This is what I'm doing

```
strftime("28/10/2014 09:05:55 p.m.", format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
##[1] "20/10/28 12:00:00 "
```

As you can see, three undesirable things are happening here:

1. The returned date is incorrect!
2. The time is always set to `12:00:00`
3. The returned value is a String, not a datetime (this is quite irrelevant... I can convert it to datetime later)

So, the specific question is: How to correctly parse this string to datetime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) try `strptime` instead of `strftime`; I'm not sure what `strftime` does, but maybe not what you think.

(2) I don't think "p.m." will work at all; you might need some judicious `gsub("p.m.","PM",...)` use.

```
strptime("28/10/2014 09:05:55 PM", format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
## [1] "2014-10-28 21:05:55 EDT"
strptime("28/10/2014 09:05:55 p.m.", format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
## NA
```

Comment: Excelent!!! I simply removed the dots and it works like a charm! `strptime(gsub('\\.', '', "28/10/2014 09:05:55 PM"), format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')` Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to change the `p.m.`'s to `PM`'s first (as well as using strptime which is appropriate for input processing:

```
> strptime(sub("p\\.m\\.", "PM", "28/10/2014 09:05:55 p.m."), format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
[1] "2014-10-28 21:05:55 PDT"
```

Of course you will also probably need to convert the `a.m.`'s to `AM`'s as well.

Comment: It turns out that case is irrelevant, it's simply a matter of removing the dots in `a.m.` and `p.m.` (right now I'm feeling a bit dumb for missing that detail)

Comment: Then `gsub("\\.","",...)` I did try several instances of putting the dots in the format spec and gave up.